# Why is plist file not automatically working?

Tags: macos, system, plist, daemon, malware

I'm running a simple malware persistence technique on mac using Launch Daemons. I have created plist file as below with a command:

```
sudo vim /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.themacjesus.mount.plist
```

the plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
          <dict>
                    <key>Label</key>
                    <string>com.companyname.task</string>
                    <key>Program</key>
                    <string>/Users/peterlin/extension.sh</string>
                    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
                    <true/>
          </dict>
</plist>
```

and the extension.sh is just a simple shell script that read names and remarks:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "what is your name?"
read name
echo "How do you do, $name?"
read remark
echo "I am $remark too!"
```

After that, I launch the plist file by:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.themacjesus.mount.plist
```

In my sense, when I turn off the notebook and restart again, it should automatically run every plist files in Launch Daemons, but it seems that it is not working at all, or do I see it the wrong way and it has already worked?

I really appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Launch Daemons don't run connected to any Terminal interface, so it has nowhere to send output or get input from.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but then I wanna ask how do I see an obvious output from this technique, or to check whether I have really modify the system process with my self-made plist? What kind of plist file can I write?

Comment: You can write output to a file in some accessible location (e.g. `echo "Running at $(date)" >>/tmp/testdaemon.out`). If you want input, that's much more complicated since daemons not only aren't attaches to any Terminal interface, they aren't even attached to user login sessions (and generally start before you've even logged in).

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You could add the StandardOutPath and StandardErrorPath keys to your plist file to capture output. But really, you should be using a Global Agent or a User Agent rather than a Global Daemon.  An agent runs in the context of the logged-in user.